# Missing watch-guess/guess phase

Tags: draw-something

Quite often, I don't get the chance to watch my opponent guess my word or to guess theirs; when I click "play" I just get given a choice of words to draw. Our success streak doesn't reset, but I'm not sure if it increments either.

Is there something one of us is doing wrong, or is this a known/common issue?

Comment: the only time this has happened to me is if I quit the game after seeing the other player guess but before picking my word to draw. The next time I'll pick the other player from the list, I'll see the words automatically. Are you sure that's not the case for you?

Comment: I do occasionally quit when I don't like any of the words I'm offered, but only so that I can immediately re-open the app and get fresh words. I suppose I could get distracted in between sometimes, but it feels like this happens too often for that to be the case.

Answer (score 5):

This tends to happen when you leave the game in a mid-turn state as suggested by JohnoBoy. I have even had it skip me guessing their word and going right on to select (Since I have a few high streaks though this was disconcerting to me).

I found that, on the iPad, finding the constantly running application and shutting it down, then starting the app back up again fixed the issue, let me see the person guess my word again and then me guess there's and Then pick a new word... which really sucked.

But anywho, removing the app from memory generally will reset the position of the turn between you and the other person.

Comment: Hm... Next time it happens, I'll try quitting and see if that lets me see their turn.

Comment: @Rawling If it does not please return here and update your question so we can try and get a better answer :)

Comment: Still playing, waiting for it to happen :p

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. When I reload I'm still presented with a choice of words.

Answer (score 3):

After consultation with one of my drawees, I've discovered that when this happens, I'm not actually missing the watch/guess phase. In fact, *my* drawing doesn't get sent to the other person at all. My second drawing, then, completes the turn.

This is disappointing - this happened to a few of my better drawings, and I now know rather than just not getting to watch the other player guess, they never got to see the drawing at all.