# Not able to see opponent's drawing in Draw Something

Tags: draw-something

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing watch-guess/guess phase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62009/missing-watch-guess-guess-phase)

I don't see my friends drawing on Draw Something. When it says it's my turn it goes right to my choices of what to draw without letting my try to guess hers. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: My girlfriend says that she's been having the same problem. Hopefully, someone knows of a fix.